# Maximum SD Speed Class for HTC Desire HD?

Tags: htc-desire-hd

Any idea what is the maximum class supported by HTC Desire HD?
I have one 4GB Class 10 microSD card, and its not able to read it...

Comment: Have you tried using the card in any other devices/readers? How is it formatted? I don't believe that the speed class of the card typically has any bearing on whether or not a device can read it (unless the device for some awful reason doesn't properly implement the SD spec).

Answer (score 2):

The speed classification of an sdcard under no circumstances compromises compatibility.

That said here's what you can try:

- Format the sdcard inside the phone
- Make sure it works with an external card reader
- Make sure it works in another phone
- Make sure your phone can use other cards.

Comment: @RichardBorscik Thanks...

How to format the SD card?

Comment: @Jwalant Should be: Settings -> storage -> Unmount -> Format sdcard